# Dickey-Fuller Test Terms

Tags: augmented-dickey-fuller

Why do we distinguish between the terms "constant", "intercept" and "drift" in the ADF test? I understand them to be analogous yet the literature seems to define "intercept" separately? For example, here is a quote:

> ... if it looks like a random walk, include the constant term. If it looks like it might be a random walk with drift, include the constant term and the intercept."

Comment: Welcome Geoffrey. Can you provide some links/citations that include the interchangeable use you mention in your post?

Comment: @Matt. Here is a section verbatim: "... if it looks like a random walk, include the constant term. If it looks like it might be a random walk with drift, include the constant term and the intercept."

Answer (score 3):

Hi: That's a very poor way that they describe the procedure. This topic can be extremely confusing if not presented clearly and in an organized way. If you haven't already looked at it, I highly suggest Hamilton's text for a really nice explanation.

What I think  they are saying ( who wrote that ? ) based on your verbatim is the following:

If you think that the underlying process is

A) $y_t = y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, then do the  DF test using

$y_t =  \beta_0 + \beta_1 \times y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ as the model to be estimated.

On the other hand,  you think that the underlying process is

B) $y_t = \mu +  y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, then do the DF test using

$y_t =  \beta_0 + \beta_1 \times t  + \beta_2 \times y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ as the model to be estimated.

Essentially, the model to be estimated should always be one level more than what is assumed under the null hypothesis. They should have been more clear with their terminology. My experience is intercept and mean  are $\beta_{0}$ and  $\mu$. The drift term is $\beta_1 t$ and is often referred to as the "trend" term.

Note that I just realized that I wrote things with respect to the DF test. The concept is the same for the ADF test except that there are differenced lagged responses added on to the regression models. My mistake there.

ADDENDUM: Note that the way I wrote it is also not the way the actual DF test is implemented. The actual test subtracts $y_{t-1}$ from both sides so that the actual test ends up being a test that the $\beta$ coefficient being tested is zero. So, there are two issues going on in my answer. I wrote it for the DF and I didn't use the differencing trick. Neither of these really effect the answer but I strongly suggest that one look at Hamilton for the gory details.

SECOND ADDENDUM: For anyone reading this answer, the topic of ADF testing is quite complicated and the cases considered here are only two out of a possible four cases. I strongly recommend reading chapter 17 in Hamilton's Time Series Analysis text for a much more detailed and enlightening discussion. Page 502 summarizes the tests but I believe that one needs to go through  the whole chapter for a clear understanding.

Comment: It all just clicked - many thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? It has been a while since I used ADF test last, but your exposition looks counterintuitive to me. Why should the model specification in the test be different from the DGP?

Comment: Hi Richard: I wrote it for the DF but it should be the same for the ADF. The way I've always thought about it intuitively speaking was that, if you don't give the actual regression the ability to estimate outside the null, then you're not being fair. By fair, I mean  that you're sort of pre-supposing that the null is true.  But it's from memory ( which could be getting worse with age ) so if you want to check Hamilton, feel free. I'm pretty sure it's correct.

Comment: Richard: Your comment reminded me of something that I failed to mention but it doesn't have to do with the order of the regression. I added an Addendum to the answer.

Comment: A quick check of Zivot & Wang "Modelling Financial Times Series with S-PLUS" (one of my favourte go-to books for time series analysis) Chapter 4 seems to confirm my concern. The model specification should reflect the DGP under the alternative; no additional terms are added, unlike in your answer.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Let me check out Hamilton and then I'll delete the answer or give a heads up or whatever you want me to do. My apologies.

Comment: @mlofton, all I am interested in is having correct answers and not having incorrect ones. I am just trying to contribute to that on topics familiar to me.

Comment: @Richard Hardy: I'm sorry for late reply. As far as I can tell, we're both half right and half wrong but that still means my answer is wrong. The gory details  are on page 502 of hamilton's text. There are 4 cases and some do what you describe and some do what I describe. If you want me to delete the answer or whatever, I can do that. The better answer is: "See page 502 of Hamilton" because I don't have the time nor the energy to go through it. To be honest though, I think OP was more interested in terminology which, AFAIK, is correct. Again, my apologies for wrong answer and late response.

Comment: @Richard Hardy: I just re-read the brown part of the OP's question and I think that what's in the brown does refer to the cases that I described. So, maybe it's best to just add another addendum and something like: "There are actually four cases where the ADF can be applied and only two cases are covered here. If you are interested in the other two cases see page 502 of Hamilton's Time Series Analysis for details". Whatever you want me to do is fine with me. In fact, maybe the suggestion should be to read the whole chapter. 502 without the rest of the chapter doesn't shed much light.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comments! I have now read Hamilton's section 17.4 and see that you do not contradict it. I think that some textbooks that were released after Hamilton suggest somewhat different treatment, but this does not mean the approach in Hamilton is inferior. I guess a reasonable economy solution (not taking too much effort from anyone) is to leave this as is and/or perhaps add the addendum you suggested. Thanks again!

Comment: @Richard Hardy: No problem. I'll add a short addendum. My answer is misleading if for no other reason than there are four cases and not two.

Comment: @mlofton, I am very interested in the original question - what's the difference between "drift", "constant" and "intercept"? From your comments, it appears "constant" is Beta0, and "drift" is Beta1 * t. Is that correct? If yes, what is "intercept"? Could you please write it as a Beta parameter?

Comment: @RichardHardy, could you please have a look at my previous comment above and see whether you could help?

Comment: @Newwone, I do not have the time at the moment. If I were you, I would take a good textbook (mlofton recommends Hamilton) and read the relevant chapter/section carefully.

Comment: @Newwone: Like Richard, I recommend going through Hamilton's chapter on this carefully because, as you can see from the discussion above between myself and Richard, the whole issue is quite confusing. There are 4 different cases where each of them corresponds to a different scenario. If I tried to explain it here, I would just end up making it more confusing. That being said, I still think Hamilton gives the best explanation on what is a confusing topic. I suggest reading his chapter carefully from start to finish.